# Recurrence relation for Pell's equation $x^2-2y^2=1$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recurrence-relations, pell-type-equations

I am wondering how to find the recurrence relation for solutions for $x$ in the Pell's equation $x^2-2y^2=1$.

I know the formula for the general term.
It is $$\frac{(3+2\sqrt2)^n+(3-2\sqrt2)^n}{2}$$ for $x_n$, the $n^{th}$ smallest solution for $x$.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

I got a feeling that the recurrence formula is $x_n=6x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}$, but I wonder how to prove this relation true/false and how to derive/generate the recurrence relation.
Note that $x_{-1}=1$ and this recurrence formula applies to all nonnegative integral $n$.

Comment: For adding more details, it is recommended that you edit your question instead of creating a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I will edit the question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular technique, but it's easy to see that $x_n = 6x_{n-1} - x_{n-2}$ satisfies the formula given. It's also not difficult to see that it is the *only* recurrence relation of the form $x_n = ax_{n-1} + bx_{n-2}$ that the formula satisfies. If you are looking for such a recurrence relation, you've found it!

Comment: I haven't learned generating functions, so I don't quite understand why it works, and why it is the only formula that work. I will try to figure that out.

Comment: Have you tried to expand the formula $x_{n+1}=6 x_n - 1 x_{n-1}$ using the fractional/exponential expression that you already have, simplify and identify the correctness of the recursion-formula?

Comment: I haven't. That would be a great and simple idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$ then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the quadratic equation $$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta=0$$

Let the quadratic be $p(x)=x^2-px+q$, then consider $$0=A\alpha^np(\alpha)+B\beta^np(\beta)=$$$$=(A\alpha^{n+2}+B\beta^{n+2})-p(A\alpha^{n+1}+B\beta^{n+1})+q(A\alpha^{n}+B\beta^{n})=u_{n+2}-pu_{n+1}+qu_n$$from which $$u_{n+2}=pu_{n+1}-qu_n$$Where $p=\alpha+\beta$ and $q=\alpha\beta$

You simply need to identify $\alpha$ and $\beta$ - the surrounding constants drop out in the arithmetic.

Once two successive terms are known, the constants $A$ and $B$ are determined, and there is a unique recurrence of this kind because two consecutive terms determine the rest through the recurrence.

Comment: Note also that you can show that the recurrence is true simply by showing that it works for the general term you have. This answer shows you how to derive it.

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence: "If $u_n = ...$ then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots [...]." Is $u_n = ...$ a definition? If so, what are $\alpha$ and $\beta$? If it's not a definition, what is $u_n$, and how are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ defined?

Comment: I think what confused me is the "If ... then ...", which seems to say that $u_n$ being defined like that *implies* $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of the quadratic, but the latter fact is independent of the former.

Comment: @Anakhand $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are automatically the roots of that quadratic, it is true and perhaps if  ... then ... is not logically required. "Consider ... [the quadratic] ..." might have been a more elegant way to put it. I was trying to emphasise the connection between the roots of polynomials and the solutions of linear recurrences (which is true for three or more roots too - this is a toy example). The connection is not as well known as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental solution is $9-8 = 1,$ meaning $3^2 - 2 \cdot 2^2 = 1.$ As a result, we have the matrix
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 4 \\
2 &3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which solves the automorphism relation, $A^T H A = H,$ where
$$
H =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
That is
$$ (3x+4y)^2 - 2 (2x+3y)^2 = x^2 - 2 y^2.  $$
Next,
$$ A^2 - 6 A + I = 0. $$
Since
$$
A
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_n \\
y_n
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n+1} \\
y_{n+1}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and
$$
A^2
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_n \\
y_n
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n+2} \\
y_{n+2}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
we find
$$ x_{n+2} - 6 x_{n+1} + x_n = 0  $$
$$ y_{n+2} - 6 y_{n+1} + y_n = 0  $$
This is just Cayley-Hamilton.

Caution: This is for $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 1.$ If we change the problem to $x^2 - 2 y^2 = 119 = 7 \cdot 17,$ the recurrence still holds, except that there are now  four such families, each using the same recursion:

$$ (11,1) \; \; \; \; (37,25) \; \; \; \; (211,149) ... $$
$$ (13,5) \; \; \; \; (59,41) \; \; \; \; (341,241) ... $$
$$ (19,11) \; \; \; \; (101,71) \; \; \; \; (587,415) ... $$
$$ (29,19) \; \; \; \; (163,115) \; \; \; \; (949,671) ... $$

If you don't mind negative values for $x,y$ you can combine the above four into two families going both forth and back...

Comment: Is this group theory?

Comment: @Kai the only group theory you need for this is how to multiply 2 by 2 integer matrices of determinant $1$

Answer (score -2):

You can find the general recurrence relationship here:

https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/contfrac/pell.html